# Remove white space from first line of textarea

Tags: php, html, submit, whitespace

how can i prevent php to remove the whitespace from the begining of the textarea first line. Everytime i submited the form, the withespace are removed...even if i replace it for nbsp;

The code i'm using:

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_cel'])){ 
    $text = trim($_POST['cel']);
    $text = explode("\n", $text);
    foreach($texto as $line){
        echo str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',$line);
    } 
}
```

The input

```
   1234 5678
abcdefghif
```

The output

```
1234 5678
abcdefghif
```

Comment: Remove  $text = trim($_POST['cel']); this line

Comment: post your html textarea

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the call to [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

> > This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP documentation :

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the trim() function if you want php to leave whitespaces as it is. If you apply trim on some string it removes whitespaces from the beginning and end of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_cel'])){ 
    $text = trim($_POST['cel']);
    $text = explode("\n", $text);
    foreach($texto as $line){
        echo trim(str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',$line));
    } 
}
```

Comment: It always helps to explain _how_ this answers the question. This answer was auto-flagged as low quality because it is a code-only answer.